# Product of two Ito processes

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am in the process of learning to use Mathematica for doing stochastic calculus.
I can do Ito's lemma by symbolic manipulation, substitutions, expansions and simplifications.

However, I feel like finding the resulting process of the product of two Ito processes should be possible using the inbuilt Ito functions. Meaning if I define Xt and Yt as Itoprocesses, is there a way to define the product and back out the drift and volatility terms?

```
(*Define the first Ito process*)
Xt = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
    Subscript[\[Mu], x]*x[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
     Subscript[\[Sigma], x]*x[t] \[DifferentialD]w[t]}, x[t], {x, 1}, 
  t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]

(*Define the second Ito process*)
Yt = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]y[t] == 
    Subscript[\[Mu], Y]*y[t] \[DifferentialD]t + 
     Subscript[\[Sigma], y]*y[t] \[DifferentialD]w[t]}, y[t], {y, 1}, 
  t, w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]]

(*Define the resulting Ito process*)
Drift[
 TransformedProcess[
  X*Y, {X  \[Distributed]  Xt, Y \[Distributed] Yt}, t]]
```

I am doing things manually using Ito's lemma in Mathematica.
And it feels like this is something I should be able to do with base functions.